# Attach stored procedure with custom type as parameter to EDMX

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6

I Created a sample stored Procedure with Custom TYPE parameter.
It executes perfectly in SQL, but I am unable to attach it to EDMX (EF 6).

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ArrayINT
AS TABLE
(
  Value INT
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteItems
(
@IDs dbo.ArrayINT READONLY
) AS
BEGIN

//...Logic to delete

END
```

Comment: "I am unable to.." - can you give some more details (edit your question) about the problems you face? Do you get any (error) messages (if so, please specify)? What steps did you (try to) perform?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of doing this. But you can work around with `ExecuteSqlCommand` and `datatable`:

```
var context = new TSQL2012Entities();

var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("SomeColumn1");
table.Columns.Add("SomeColumn2");
table.Rows.Add(someValue11, someValue21);
table.Rows.Add(someValue21, someValue22);

var param = new SqlParameter("param1", SqlDbType.Structured);
param.Value = table;
param.TypeName = "[dbo].[YourTableType]";

string command = "EXEC spProcName @param1";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command, param);
```